# Is it redundant to have both hearing and "sensory hairs"?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, senses

After watching [Because Science's video about spider sensory organs that could enable Spider-Mans' Spider-Sense](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygt6W64gatE&t=457s), I got interested in implementing trichobotria -- the sensory hairs you see on tarantulas and other big hairy spiders:

[image]

These hairs let them perceive minute vibrations in the air at a distance. I need to know how different is it from simply hearing?

I mean, yeah, it's super sensitive, but hearing could also be super sensitive.

The only advantage I can think of is that , because it would be spread all over your skin, it would be more precise at perceiving the direction of the stymulus, but it's not like ears cannot do this to some extent, so I'm not so sure if it's worth the effort (the animals that have thricobothria don't have ears after all), so it's not like it's it's that different from hearing...

Is there any reason to have both eardrums and sensory hairs?

Comment: VTC:NAW (a) Stack Exchange is NOT a discussion forum. We only answer specific questions about the rules or needs of your imaginary world. (b) You are allowed one and only one question per post. (c) Just because this feels like a "can I do this in Real Life?" question, we don't answer those kinds of questions. Per the [help/on-topic], "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site for designers, writers, artists, gamers and enthusiasts to get help creating imaginary worlds."

Comment: [Trichobothria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichobothria) *"are elongate setae ("hairs") present in arachnids, various orders of insects, and myriapods that function in the detection of airborne vibrations and currents, and electrical charge"*. (Wikipedia.) The name means "socketed hairs" in Greek. They are different from hearing in that (1) they are physical organs, whereas hearing is the sense provided by organs, and (2) besides vibrations, they sense air currents and electric charges, thus combining the functions of severeal different mammalian organs.

Comment: Don't use technical jargon in your questions. It doesn't make the question any better and leads to worse answers. If I have to look up "trichobotria" to understand the question then you have wasted a perfectly good title.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections @Daron

Comment: The human Vestibular system (part of the inner ear in most mammals, but not related to hearing) uses specialized hairs to detect the movement of fluids to stimulate a sense of balance, awareness, and direction of movement in humans.